# How to send a query to the database using GET through an REST API (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: api, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to add a query parameter to a GET request such a way that my REST API returns the query's result instead of the result from default index method.

Is this possible?

Here is my index method:

```
  def index
    users = User.all
    render(
      json: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(
        users,
        each_serializer: Api::V1::UserSerializer,
        root: 'users'
      )
    )
  end
```

I would like to have an additional method named my_new_index executable by a GET or I would like to have a query submitted as a parameter to the default index method, lets say something like this:

```
query = "select * from users where name like 'A%' order by name desc"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do but what I would suggest is using the same end point index to return your content filtered.
First I'll start by creating a scope like:

```
scope :starting_with, ->(letter) { where('users.name like ?', "#{letter}%") if letter }
```

Then update you index end point to something like:

```
def index
  users = User.starting_with(params[:letter]).all
  render(
    json: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(
      users,
      each_serializer: Api::V1::UserSerializer,
      root: 'users'
    )
  )
end
```

In this quick example the end point receive the params, if it contains a `letter` params, it will render users filtered by the scope query. If the param is not present, it return all users.
FYI it's just a quick example and not perfect, I'm sure you could find ways improve it.

Hope it helps :)